# prepareForSegue function not working

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am sure I have two view controllers, that have the appropriate files as their classes. (ViewController1.swift and ViewController2.swift) I am trying to pass data from one of the view controllers to the other one with the following code; but I get the error "UIView Controller is not convertible to ViewController2". What should I do? I tried to change as to as! and var to let; neither worked.

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!){

        if (segue.identifier == "btnSubmitSegue") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2;
        svc.DataPassed = textField.text

    }
}
```

the code for ViewController2
     import UIKit

```
 class ViewController2: UIViewController {

var toPass: String = ""
 @IBOutlet weak var labeld: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      self.labeld.text = "passed: \(self.toPass)"

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

the code for ViewController1

```
  import UIKit

  class ViewController1: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "TheSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
        vc.toPass = self.textField.text!
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: There's no `ViewController2` in the above code.  Is this the actual code that resulted in that error?  If not, can you post the code that produces the error `UIViewController is not convertible to ViewController2`.

Comment: That is not the problem. I chose ViewController2 to ask the question, now I changed it in the above code too. What is the real problem:)?

Comment: is your ViewController2 extending UIViewController class ?

Comment: Yes, when I created the Cocoa File, I chose UIViewController Class

Comment: Please show the code from `ViewController1.swift` and `ViewController2.swift` in your question.

Comment: I added the code to the question

Answer (score 2):

The following example works fine for me. Code for the first view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "TheSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
            vc.passedText = self.textField.text!
        }
    }
}
```

And in the second view controller:

```
    class ViewController2: UIViewController {
        var passedText: String = ""
        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.label.text = "passed: \(self.passedText)"
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to name the segue in the Storyboard:

[image]

Your destination view controller is referring to the wrong controller. You should have this in your code, not `as! ViewController1`:

```
let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
```

Also need to fix your `IBOutlet` name, the `vc.toPass = self.textField.text!` should be:

```
vc.toPass = self.labeld.text!
```

Make sure the custom class is set for the second view controller:

[image]

Comment: @ArdaBoğa Please add the rest of your code to your question. It will help people answer your question. Otherwise, there may be something causing an issue that we don't know about.

Comment: I just added it to the question

Comment: @ArdaBoğa Ok, I updated my answer. It looks like your destination view controller is wrong.

Comment: It is not the problem; when I posted the question, I changed the names of controllers and made a mistake when I wrote the question here. So, it refers to the controller 2. Still stuck:S

Comment: @ArdaBoğa How is your segue connected between the view controllers?

Comment: The botton of controller1 goes to the controller2

Comment: I receive the following error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelPassedData.' But I do not even have a variable like labelPassedData

Comment: @ArdaBoğa Updated my answer again. If you are still having trouble, read my article at http://tinkker.io/swift/2015/11/14/prepareforsegue.html

Comment: @ArdaBoğa Were you able to figure out your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the help, we decided to use Parse to store and retrieve the data, so it was necessary to send data between view controllers

Answer (score 0):

It may just be that ViewController2 is not declared as a subclass as UIViewController.
At the top of the ViewController2 file you would declare it as follows:

```
    class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    \\ ...

}
```

Comment: It is declared as a subclass as UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the name in the Storyboard ? Under custom class, Class needs to point to the view controllers associated class.

[image]

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   labelPassedData.' But I do not even have a variable like
>   labelPassedData

Click you view controller and press right hand arrow button, it shows all connections.

[image]

I guess you copy and pasted the view controllers and hence you get this problem.